# Combine two variable input field become one to submit backend

Tags: angular, typescript

I've code two input field, one for mydate and one for mytime. Before submit to backend, I want to combine become one. Example, `<input type="text" name="myDate">` `<input type="text" name="myTime">` and when submit form `myDate` and `myTime` become one variable etc `myDateTime`.

Example code and demo I provide bellow.

**HTML**

```
<form  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"
    novalidate>
<div  class="form-group">
    <div class="date-ctrl">
    <label> Date</label>
    <input class="form-control short" [(ngModel)]="myDate"  matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
           (dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle class="img-calendar" matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</div>
<div class="time-ctrl">
<label>time</label>
 <input class="form-control shot" [(ngModel)]="myDate" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer-dialog">
    <div class="field-bottom">
        <span class="ctrl-button">
        <button class="dialog-button save-color"  mat-button type="submit">Save</button>
        </span>

    </div>
</div>


</form>
```

**Component**

```
createForm() {
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        myDate: [''],
        myTime: ['']
      });
      // const myDateTime = myDate myTime
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }


}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-example-jezujg) for more reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your original stackblitz demo (which is quite broken) I've fixed it enough to demonstrate what you are after:

datepicker-filter-example.ts:

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  FormGroupDirective,
  NgForm
} from "@angular/forms";

/** @title Datepicker with filter validation */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-filter-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerFilterExample implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}
  public form: FormGroup;
  dateFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const day = d.getDay();
    // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }

  ngOnInit():void{
    this.createForm();
  }

  addEvent(v1:any, v2: any){
    console.log('Add Event Called');
  }

  myFilter(d: Date): boolean {
        const day = d.getDay();
    const month = d.getMonth();
        const todays_date = d.getDate();
        const todaysDateObject = new Date();
        const today = todaysDateObject.getDate();
    const actualMonth = todaysDateObject.getMonth();
    console.log(todays_date)

        /** Prevent actual system date from being selected.*/
    if (month === actualMonth && todays_date === today) {
      return false;
    } else if (day !== 0 && day !== 6) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

        /** Prevent Saturday, Sunda.*/
//        return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
    }



 createForm() {
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        myDate: new FormControl(),
        myTime: new FormControl(),
      });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const combined = `${this.form.get('myDate').value} ${this.form.get('myTime').value}`;
    console.log(combined);
  }

}
```

datepicker-filter-example.html

```
    <form  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"
    novalidate>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="date-ctrl">
    <label>Date</label>
    <input class="form-control short" formControlName="myDate"  matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
           (dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle class="img-calendar" matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</div>

<div class="time-ctrl">
    <label>Time</label>
    <input class="form-control shot" formControlName="myTime" />
</div>

</div>

<div class="footer-dialog">
    <div class="field-bottom">
        <span class="ctrl-button">
        <button class="dialog-button save-color"  mat-button type="submit">Save & Start</button>
        </span>

    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother...So sorry.. I really bad on code...

Comment: Can I ask you one more question... let say I've another variable to send to backend. Example UserId.. What should I do?

Comment: @Pravu - all good - take a look at the HttpClient info here - https://angular.io/guide/http you will need to create another FormControl similar to what I added to your original code called "UserId" then use this.form.get('UserId').value to get the value - then follow the HttpClient documentation to send the data to the server

Answer (score 1):

You have options:

- You can just translate/map the form on submit
- You can create a custom form control that allows you to enter date and time and binds to a single value

I suspect you want to create custom form field.

For specifics on how to create and register Custom Form Controls, take a look at this article:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

To make this all work well with Angular Material, see this documentation
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html